# How do I display a message that a user is banned on the login page of a Vue component in Laravel

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

So I'm using this middleware in Laravel to check if a user is blocked and then logout them out if they are:

```
class IsUserBanned
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (auth()->check() && auth()->user()->banned_until != null) {

            if (auth()->user()->banned_until == 0) {
                $message = 'Your account has been banned permanently.';
            }
            if (now()->lessThan(auth()->user()->banned_until)) {
                $banned_days = now()->diffInDays(auth()->user()->banned_until) + 1;
                $message = 'Your account has been suspended for ' . $banned_days . ' ' . Str::plural('day', $banned_days);
            }

            return redirect()->route('login')->with(auth('web')->logout())->with('message', $message);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I know that to display the message in a blade.php I would use something like this:

```
<div class="card-body">
 
    @if (session('message'))
        <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ session('message') }}</div>
    @endif
 
    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
```

My question is how would I do the same thing in a Vue component? Would a v-if work? I'm new to Vue so sorry if this is a stupid question...

Edit:: My guess is something like this but it's not working

```
<div v-if="message" class="mb-4 font-medium text-sm text-red-600">
   {{ message }}
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried something with vue? your data are coming from api or web?

Comment: I'm using inertia and vue2

Comment: Can you show us how you are handling the state for message?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, have I missed something? Like I said I'm new to Vue trying to convert all my blades to a Vue SPA normally those first two code snippets worked fine, do I need to store the message state? sorry for the stupid questions

Answer (score 1):

Vue doesn't have access to the Laravel session state by default, since that could result in information leakage. Something like you proposed (using a `v-if` directive to display the message) *would* work, but you still have to pass the message to the frontend somehow.

If you're using [Laravel Jetstream](https://jetstream.laravel.com/2.x/introduction.html) with [Inertia](https://inertiajs.com/) and Vue, you can simply pass the `message` element of the session to your frontend as a Vue prop.

In your Vue component (if you're using Single File Components it'll be in a `*.vue` file), you'd need to add it to your props array, something like this:

```js
// template up here ...

export default {
  data() { ... },
  props: ['message'] // add to this array
  // ...
}
```

And then you'll need to pass the prop when you [*render* an Inertia response](https://inertiajs.com/responses) on the Laravel side. If you follow your `login` route, you'll eventually find a call to `Inertia::render` or the `inertia(...)` helper. You'd add the session to the property array there, something like this:

```php
// probably in routes/web.php

Route::get('/login', function() {
  // more code ...

  Inertia::render('Login', [ 'message' => session('message') ]);
});
```

This is how you'd do this for passing properties to a page in general, **however,** if you're using the uncustomized default login view provided by Laravel Fortify through Jetstream's starter, you'll need to take additional steps:

- The Vue SFC you're editing is likely in `resources/js/Pages/Auth/Login.vue`
- The Inertia response rendering that page is normally automatically handled by the framework. To customize it, you'll need to follow [these instructions](https://jetstream.laravel.com/2.x/features/authentication.html#customizing-inertia-authentication-views) and use code that looks closer to this:

```php
Fortify::loginView(function () {
    return Inertia::render('Auth/Login', [
        'message' => session('message')
    ]);
});
```

Comment: You're an absolute legend! I had to customise my handleinertiarequests middleware just adding 'message' => session('message') at the end, then add the props to my vue component, but it worked thank you so much for the detailed explanation and accompanying docs saved me a massive headache! Tried to upvote your answer but I'm new here and can't cast votes yet will be sure to come back and upvote when I can, thanks again!

Comment: @Joe Black Any time! Glad I was able to help! Even though you can't upvote, you should be able to click the check to mark this answer as accepted!